# how disable scrolling when bingmap focus?

Tags: javascript, bing-api, bing-maps

I have a bingmap its width and height is more than parent div. Then prent div set to be scrollable,

"*when scrolling prent scroll bar down and click the bingmap, suddenly the parent scrolling to top position*"

"*or scroll to bottom and click outside the bingmap and click inside you can see the scroll bars scrolling to top*"

how to **dissable** this effect?

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 400px; height: 200px;">
  <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 200vh;position: relative;'></div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var map;

  function loadMapScenario() {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
      credentials: ''
    });
  }
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
```

Comment: Any reason why you wrap a scrolling/zooming map in a smaller container? It's not great user experience.

Comment: @DarthJDG actually my map height is more than view port height, therefore when user scroll bottom to the map and click it it suddenly scrolls up.

Comment: Seems to only happen on the first click. As DarthJDG mentioned, this does seem like an odd user experience having the map inside of aa scrollable div.

Comment: @rbrundritt yes it only happen first click is there anyway to stop it? my application has more widgets and etc other than map

Answer (score 0):

finally I added a patch into my code. Restore parent(my case its `window`) scroll position to previous position. logic is save scroll position when mouse down on the map and restore it when window scroll.

```
var scrollPositionY = -1;
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'mousedown', function(e){

   scrollPositionY = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

   $(window).bind('scroll',preventWindowScroll);
   setTimeout(function(){
       $(window).unbind('scroll',preventWindowScroll);
   },100);
});

function preventWindowScroll(e){
   window.scrollTo(0,scrollPositionY);//restore to saved position
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
```